# call 3 restful api Continuously in camel

Tags: json, rest, api, apache-camel, postman

I have a web service that calls an API with the name of API1, then if the response of API1 is `{"result":"0"}` the second API, API2, will be called. API2 is for uploading a file and if the uploading finish successful, the third API, API3, will be called. My problem is the message body does not send to API3 properly without any error!

My code is as below:
first I send a post request with the content of:

```
{
    "API1": {
        "version": "Tooba_Uni_Appv0.4.1.apk"
    },
    "API2": {
        "password": "password",
        "username": "username",
        "file": "/home/.../index.png"
    },
    "API3": {
        "lastVer": "apk.1.10.0"
    }
}
```

The setMainBody process set the content of the message as the init content mentioned above.

```
<camelContext id="camel-CallAPI" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >
    <!-- Web service starts working -->
    <restConfiguration component="restlet" host="192.168.100.232" port="8889"/>
    <rest path="/say">
        <post uri="/hi" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
            <to uri="direct:start"/>
        </post> 
    </rest>  

    <route>         
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
            <setProperty propertyName="mainBody">
                <simple>${body}</simple>
            </setProperty>
            <removeHeaders pattern="*" excludePattern="Content-Type|CamelHttpMethod"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CONTENT_TYPE" >
                <constant>application/json</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <process ref="getVersionParam"/>
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
            <log message="before api1 and after process :: ${body}"/> 
            <to uri="direct:first"/>               
    </route>  

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:first"/>    
            <to uri="http4://...path to API1"/>
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
            <log message="after api1 :: ${body}"/> 
            <log message="if the result is 0 the Upload API should be called, otherwise the result should be stored in queue!"/>
            <!-- <setProperty propertyName="BodyAfterAPI1">
                     <simple>${body}</simple>
                 </setProperty> -->
            <setProperty propertyName="AccessResultAPI1">
                <jsonpath>$.result</jsonpath>
            </setProperty>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <!-- the testCheckLastVersion API does not work fine and The result of API will be stored in the queue-->
                    <simple>${property.AccessResultAPI1} != '0'</simple>
                    <inOnly id="ErrorQueueTestVersion" uri="activemq:queue:ErrorQueueTestVersionAPI"/> 
                    <log message="the testCheckLastVersion API has a problem and the Upload API can not be called."/>
                </when>
                <when>
                    <!-- the testCheckLastVersion API works fine and Upload API must be called-->
                    <simple>${property.AccessResultAPI1} == '0'</simple>
                    <log message="the testCheckLastVersion work fine  and the Upload API will be call soon,${property.AccessResultAPI1}"/>
                    <to uri="direct:callUploadAPI" />
                </when>
            </choice> 
    </route>

    <route id="route_callUploadAPI">
        <from uri="direct:callUploadAPI" id="from_callUploadAPI"/>
            <process ref="setMainBody"/>
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
            <log message="pure body: ${body}"/>
            <removeHeaders pattern="*" excludePattern="Content-Type|CamelHttpMethod"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CONTENT_TYPE" >
                <constant>multipart/form-data</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <process ref="getUploadParam"/>
            <to uri="http4://...path to upload API2"/>
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
            <log message="the Upload API: ${body} :: if the success was 1 the third API will be called "/>
            <setProperty propertyName="AccessResultAPI2">
                <jsonpath>$.success</jsonpath>
            </setProperty>
            <choice>
                <when>
                <!--when the Upload API does not works fine and the result of Upload API must be stored in the queue-->
                    <simple>${property.AccessResultAPI2} != '1'</simple>
                    <inOnly id="ErrorQueueAPIUpload" uri="activemq:queue:ErrorQueueUploadAPI"/> 
                    <log message="the Upload API has a problem and the TestsetVersion API can not be called."/>
                </when>
                <!--when the Upload API works fine and TestsetLastVersion API must be called-->
                <when>
                    <simple>${property.AccessResultAPI2} == '1'</simple>
                    <log message="the Upload API works, success: ${property.AccessResultAPI2}"/>
                    <to uri="direct:midle"/>
                </when>
            </choice>
    </route>

    <route>         
        <from uri="direct:midle"/>
            <!-- <process ref="setMainBody"/>
                 <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>-->
            <log message="body aftre setMainbody: ${body}"/> 
            <removeHeaders pattern="*" excludePattern="Content-Type|CamelHttpMethod"/>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod" >
                <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="CONTENT_TYPE" >
                <constant>application/json</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <!-- <process ref="getLastVersionParam"/> 
                 <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>-->
            <setBody>
                <constant>{"lastVer":"apk.1.10.0"}</constant>
            </setBody>
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
            <to uri="http4://...path to API3"/> 
            <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/> 
            <log message="the testsetLastVersion API: ${body}"/>                
            <log message="The TestsetLastversion API is ok and the process finished successfuly."/>
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

the problem is that, the content of body does not send to the third API and it doesn't return response!

Comment: when I'm tracing my routes; the header is set to :                                             Headers:{CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpResponseCode=200, CamelHttpResponseText=OK, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=33, Content-Type=text/html; charset=utf-8, CONTENT_TYPE=application/json, Date=Sun, 17 Feb 2019 10:34:52 GMT, ETag=W/"21-aGnLNYY0nGDZGzCePbyRALlx15k", X-Powered-By=Express}                               how can I remove Content-Type=text/html; charset=utf-8 from it?

Comment: To the question in your comment on how to remove headers automatically, you can use a [HttpHeaderFitlerStrategy](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Jetty-consumer-responds-with-a-500-error-java-io-IOException-Response-header-too-large-td5816258.html#a5816296) which either allows you to prevent Camel from coping HTTP headers to the Camel exchange header (`applyFilterToExternalHeaders(...)`) or from copying the exchange headers to the HTTP header (`applyFilterToCamelHeaders()`)

Comment: As you use HTTP4Component, could you add `<logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug"/>` to your logback (or log4j) configuration and see what raw-http out and in messages you've got? Maybe the second call does return anything other than `0` and therefore does not invoke the upload API. I'd also avoid `when` blocks that should cover all the other outcomes and instead use `otherwise` instead as explained [here](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html)

Comment: thank you Roman Vottner for your response, I found that my content-type did not set correctly, and that was the reason of sending empty body to the third API. Thanks so much for your time.